# Knockout binding issue on Aurelia cached views

Tags: knockout.js, aurelia

I have a web app which runs on the Aurelia CLI and uses knockout for its bindings (because the previous app which I am converting to Aurelia used knockout extensively). For that I am using the Aurelia-knockout plugin without problems.

I have made (as a test) two simple views (and corresponding routes):

```
#/test1
#/test2
```

These are the views:

```
<!-- test1.html -->
<template view-cache="*">
    <div knockout>
        <br /><br />
        <div data-bind="foreach: values1">
            <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- test2.html -->
<template view-cache="*">
    <div knockout>
        <br /><br />
        <div data-bind="foreach: values2">
            <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

As you can see from the html, I am caching the views [using the "view-cache" attribute](http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/09/05/aurelia-early-september-release-notes/), so that they won’t be reloaded when I navigate back to that view.
The corresponding models are simply defined like so:

```
//test1.js
export class Test1 {        
    values1 = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);
}

//test2.js
export class Test2 {        
    values2 = ko.observableArray([4,5,6]);
}
```

This is my router configuration:

```
routes = [                    
    { route: ['', 'test1'], moduleId: 'views/test1', name: 'test1' },
    { route: ['test2'], moduleId: 'views/test2', name: 'test2' } 
];

config.map(routes);
```

When I first load the page, I correctly see

```
123
```

when I navigate to #/test2 I correctly see

```
456
```

but if I navigate back to #test1 I see

```
112233
```

if I now go again to #test2 I see there also the numbers ‘duplicated’. And every time I go back and forth, the numbers are always added. For example, if I visit #test1 4 times, I get

```
111122223333
```

NOTE: If I don’t cache the views (by omitting the "view-cache" attribute) everything works ok.

But I would like to use view caching. I know from what I’ve read that this is a feature the Aurelia team is still working on, I would just like to know if anyone has had the same issue and how to solve it. It looks as if the knockout bindings are “added” to the already present ones every time navigation occurs.

**Update**

I just tried using the [singleton decorator](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/290) like this:

```
import * as Framework from 'aurelia-framework';

@Framework.singleton()
export class Test1 {                
    activated = false;
    values1 = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);

    constructor(){
        console.log('constructed')
    }

    activate() {
        if (this.activated) {
            console.log('activated')
            var val = this.values1();
            this.values1([]);
            this.values1([1,2,3]);
            console.log(this.values1())
        } else this.activated = true;
    }
}
```

What has changed is that the constructor is no longer called, and the state of the viewModel is persisted (which means, the second time I navigate to #test1, the variable "activated" is true.

Still, the output of the knockout binding is the same as before.

Comment: how about using `ko.observableArray` instead of `ko.observable`?

Comment: sorry yes, of course I wanted to  use observableArrays. Anyway I just tried that and nothing changed. (I have corrected the code in the question)

Comment: how about clearing the array before filling it? like `values1 = ko.observableArray([]);` and then assigning `[1,2,3]` to the array `values1([1,2,3]);`

Comment: @gkb, that does not work either. I tried also to put some "re-initialization" code like the one you suggested in the activate() callback but the problem is that the view is completely recreated, even its constructor() method is called again (in my example there is none but I have tried as well). I am now exploring an approach with the "@ singleton" decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a logic problem in your activate method.
I believe it should read

`if (!this.activated) ....`

and move the

`this.activated = true`

inside the if something like this

`activate() {
        if (!this.activated) {
            console.log('activated')
            var val = this.values1();
            this.values1([]);
            this.values1([1,2,3]);
            console.log(this.values1());
            this.activated = true;
        }
    }`

Comment: No, if it is not yet activated I just want to set it to activated and nothing else. If it is already activated, I want to try to reset the property in order to see if the knockout binding works. The problem is that every additional visit to the page "adds" the same values again and again to the observable property bound to the html (as I described)

Comment: That is because each time the object is activated your code adds the values to the array. You should initialize the array once when you activate the object, then on previous activations do nothing.

Comment: My code does not 'add' values to the array, it just resets the values of the array. Anyway, it was just an additional test that I did, if you take a look at my question before the "update" section there is no "activate" logic and still the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a way to bypass the issue, using the KnockoutBindable [as explained here](https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout):

```
//test1.html (and test2.html, same code only with variable name values1 instead of values2)
<template view-cache="*">
    <div knockout>
        <div repeat.for="item of values2">
            ${item}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

//test1.js (and test2.js, same as above)
import * as Framework from 'aurelia-framework';
import {KnockoutBindable} from "aurelia-knockout";
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@Framework.singleton()
@inject(KnockoutBindable)
export class Test2 {        
    activationData = {
        values2: ko.observableArray([4,5,6])
    }
    knockoutBindable;

    @Framework.bindable
    values2;

    constructor(kb) {
        this.knockoutBindable = kb;        
    }

    activate() {
        this.knockoutBindable.applyBindableValues(this.activationData, this); 
    }
}
```

Now if I go back and forth the values are correctly kept.
The disadvantage of this is that I would have to create an extra variable which "mirrors" the knockout variable, and which in the html uses the aurelia syntax just to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taken [from here](https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout/issues/8#issuecomment-267410874):

Aurelia caches the whole "View" object (including the document-fragment which holds the html) if you switch to another view. If you go back, Aurelia uses the cached view and binds it against your new view-model. This works fine because all Aurelia bindings are processed again completly. But the templating engine doesn't know the Knockout syntax which dynamically generates html too. It treats it as "normal html" and doesn't revert the changes from previous runs.

This plugin calls ko.cleanNode(...) if the unbind callback is invoked from Aurelia. This reverts the changes Knockout made before (so exactly what you need). Unfortunately the callback is called too late. The old view is already detached and this cleaning takes no effect. The document-fragment is cached as is.